# Generating waveforms with ChiselTest framework

Tags: chisel

I have a ChiselTest tester written as follows:

```
class EccTester extends FlatSpec with ChiselScalatestTester with Matchers {
    behavior of "Testers2"
  it should "send data without errors" in {
    test(new EccPair(width=8)) {
      c => {
        val rnd = new Random()
        for (i <- 0 to 20) {
          val testVal = rnd.nextInt(1 << c.getWidthParam)

          c.io.dataIn.poke(testVal.U)
          c.io.errorLocation.poke(0.U)
          c.io.injectError.poke(false.B)
          c.io.injectSecondError.poke(false.B)
          c.clock.step(1)
          c.io.dataOut.expect(testVal.U)
          c.io.outputNotEqual.expect(false.B)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to run the test in the shell with

testOnly chisel.lib.ecc.EccTester

But when I try to generate waveforms per the ChiselTest documentation,

testOnly chisel.lib.ecc.EccTester -- -DvwriteVcd=1

The test executes OK but does not dump a waveform.

Documentation I referenced is https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2, and the full source code is at https://github.com/hutch31/ip-contributions/blob/ecc/src/test/scala/chisel/lib/ecc/EccTester.scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think there is a formal answer to this yet, but here’s what I do. First I add the two following imports.

```
import chiseltest.experimental.TestOptionBuilder._
import chiseltest.internal.WriteVcdAnnotation
```

then add the annotation to the test like this

```
  it should "send data without errors" in {
    test(new EccPair(width=8)).withAnnotations(Seq(WriteVcdAnnotation)) {
      c => {
```

Note: there are two definitions of WriteVcdAnnotation, one is in package treadle
and the other is in package chiseltest.internal. Use the latter, as it will work
for both treadle and verilator backends.

Comment: With chisel 3.5.0, `chiseltest.experimental.TestOptionBuilder` is gone. And `WriteVcdAnnotation` is now in `simulator` : `import chiseltest.simulator.WriteVcdAnnotation` is enough now. discussion in mailling list : https://groups.google.com/g/chisel-users/c/UGbBiN_VyHg